# Is there a way to implement a health check service for Eventhub - queue in Azure for resource monitoring

Tags: azure-eventhub, health-check, webmethods, resource-monitor, transient-failure

Requirement -

From webMethods we are sending event driven messages to Azure Eventhub queues over http. We are looking for an option to have a health check service on the availability of the queue rather than the landing zone to handle transient errors.

What are we trying to achieve -

We are basically trying to implement a transient error handler over resource monitoring in webMethods to avoid unnecessary automated prod alerts for high volume interfaces. Also to have a automated suspend and retry mechanism of feeds rather than doing it manually.

Please do let me know if there is a way to implement this solution.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are four transient exceptions in Azure Event Hubs messaging which can be generated by using .NET framework API.

- [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagingexception?view=azure-dotnet)
- [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ServerBusyException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-messaging-exceptions#serverbusyexception)
- [Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.ServerBusyException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-messaging-exceptions#serverbusyexception)
- [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingCommunicationException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagingcommunicationexception?view=azure-dotnet)

Additionally from this, there are 3 top approaches to monitor the health status of Azure Event Hubs.

- Metric Based Monitoring
- Azure Event Hub Logging

  - Activity Log
  - Diagnostic Log
- Status Monitoring

**Note:** Monitoring the Azure resource status does not mean monitoring the physical status of a resource, but it also includes monitoring availability, performance, reliability, and consumption.

To know more about these approaches and to implement them, please refer this [third-party tutorial](https://www.serverless360.com/blog/monitor-azure-event-hub-health-status#:%7E:text=The%20Azure%20metric%20monitor%20provides,portal%20to%20monitor%20Event%20Hubs.).